# How to manipulate browser in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, browser

I have a application, which need to login to a website, and the website has capcha. So I want to open a browser to let user login so the app can get the session or cookie.
I have tried Selenium, but it seems dosen't work in classlib project.

Comment: you have the browser controls in windows Forms app, do you want similar one from a class library project?

Comment: @Saravanan actually, this project is a classlib, so the WinForm may not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a lib called `puppeteer`, and it has .net version [puppeteer-sharp](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp).